# Can't install Parallels Tools on Debian 7.2.0

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo, root, parallels

(Parallels Desktop 9, latest version)

As per instructions, I switch to root:

```
$ su - root
$ whoami
root
$ echo $EUID
0
```

and then execute the installer:

```
$ cd /media/cdrom0
$ ./install
```

and I get this error:

```
sudo: unable to execute ./install: Permission denied
```

What? I'm root! What's with this? I double check to make sure the execute bit is set:

```
$ ls -lA | grep install$
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  17284 Oct 25 09:22 install
```

Yep. People [online](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?104180-Parallels-6-Ubuntu-10-04-How-to-install-Parallels-Tools) are saying that you need to drag the install script to the terminal after typing sudo. So I do that, and this command is what's formed:

```
$ sudo '/media/cdrom0/install'
sudo: unable to execute /media/cdrom0/install: Permission denied
```

What's the solution here?

Comment: What does `file /media/cdrom0/install` say?

Comment: `/media/cdrom0/install: ERROR: cannot read '/media/cdrom0/install' (Input/output error)` Weird, because before, I had run `cat install` and it worked fine. Now it fails even after a reboot...

Comment: Try to copy the whole content of the CD to your HDD: e.g. with `cp -r /media/cdrom0 /tmp`

Answer (score 18):

So I found the solution... this crazy command (well, not so crazy, but obscure).

```
$ mount -t iso9660 -o exec /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

Turns out when Debian mounts a CD (virtual CD included of course) it mounts it as non-executable. So manually remounting it specifying exec privileges allowed me to install the tools. It's weird that the non-exec mount prevented me from even *reading* the files (I tried copying them and got similar errors) but eh, whatever works.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for this is that Parallels mounts the image with "nosuid" option.

Start a terminal, su to root and unmount the image. Remount the image. Start the installer

```
$ su
$ umount /media/cdrom
$ mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
$ cd /media/cdrom
$ sh installer
```

Comment: maybe the script name got changed but it is `install` right now so do `sh install` instead of `sh installer`

Answer (score 4):

10.13.2014: This was extremely helpful!

I've tried the steps noted on Parallels:

- How do I install Parallels Tools in Ubuntu Virtual Machine? http://kb.parallels.com/en/113394
- Parallels Tools manual installation http://kb.parallels.com/en/112609
- And a couple of other sites as well that I no longer know the link to (not going through my History)

The key, for me, was to:
• unmount the CD via Parallels: *Devices / CD/DVD 1 / Disconnect*
• remount the CD via Parallels: *Devices / CD/DVD 1 / Connect Image...*
     - Search for the ***prl-tools-lin.iso*** in: 
 *Macintosh HD / Applications / Parallels Desktop / Contents / Resources / Tools / prl-tools-lin.iso*
• While in Debian, load the Terminal if you haven't done so already
• Navigate to the CD as noted above:

```
$ cd /media/cdrom0
```

• To make sure things are in order, lets type list to see what's inside the cd (confirming, basically):

```
$ ls
```

This should list "install installer install-gui kmods tools version". If you don't see this, you'll have to try and remount the disk. I'd suggest doing the first couple of steps via Parallels.
If it works as it should, let's go ahead and copy the files to your home directory:

```
$ sudo cp -r /media/cdrom0 /home/***<USERNAME>***/Downloads/
```

I did the Downloads folder instead of tmp folder as noted above because I could not get into the tmp folder even as root. Downloads at least lets me go in, delete and confirm all via the gui if I get lazy.

• Once done, let's confirm that the cp took place:

```
$ cd /home/***<USERNAME>***/Downloads/cdrom0/
$ ls
```

• You should be able to see the following if it worked out:

```
install installer install-gui kmods tools version
```

If everything is still going according to what I've noted above, then let's go ahead and install **Parallels Tools**:
No need to get out of the folder you're in. Therefore, if you've been doing most of what I've noted, you should be in the Downloads folder or the folder which you copied the files to.
Let's run the installer:

```
$ sudo ./install
```

It will ask you for your password due sudo; let's go ahead and do so.
If all went well, you should see your terminal turning into a greyish/blue sceen w. Parallels Tools Installer (tried to upload an image but I'm still new here - sorry)

Hope this helps. I know I've read several sites and spent different parts of my weekend trying to get this running.

Comment: So, does this actually resolve the issue (answer the question)?

Comment: It did for me. Now I can go from Debian to MacOSX 10.10 or 10.9 without any issues so far.

Answer (score 2):

To make your disk or image executable you have to edit the /etc/fstab file.
Normally in the last line you will find something like `udf,iso9660 user,noauto`. Remove the `noauto`and insert instead `exec`.
Remount your disk or image and now you can execute the commands from a terminal window.